# Horizontal colorscale Plotly Express

Tags: python, plotly-python, plotly-express

Is there a possibilty in Plotly Express to set the color scale horizontal under the graph.
Here is my code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(df, x="year", y="Temperature", trendline="ols",
                 color="Temperature", color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Hot_r)
```

I tried:
fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar_orientation="h")
but just get an error.

Comment: Earlier versions had errors, but the latest version (5.5.0) has been improved. What version are you currently using? If it is old, I would recommend upgrading.

Comment: I use the newest version 5.5 but get this error: ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.coloraxis.ColorBar: 'orientation' Did you mean "bordercolor"?....Et cetera

Comment: In the colab it seems fine, i use pycharm and streamlit to show my plot but even with copying your code i get an error

Comment: That's about all I can help you with, I'll disable Colab. I don't know why the error message is showing graph_objects.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add:

```py
fig.update_layout(coloraxis=dict(colorbar=dict(orientation='h', y=-0.15)))
```